# Issue with cloned website -domain hosting information missing in clone

Tags: server, dns, cloning

When I cloned my web site with All-in-one WP Migration and overwrote another web site with this copy I lost the cloned website's domain hosting information how do I retrieve this?

When I now lookup the cloned website on IICAN I get these messages. My Original website is dancesportconfidence.com and it is still fine but the error has come up on the cloned copy of this website at dancestudio.com.au We are adding a Laravel theme to this to build a membership portal for our working website and I need to know the hosting information. I know that the name servers are through Cloudflare and Cloudflare has asked me to change the Name Servers to different ones.is but I'm not entirely sure who the WHOIIS server or the registrar is.

Domain Name Registration Data Lookup
Enter a domain name - dancestudio.com.au

Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)LookupBy submitting any personal data, I acknowledge and agree that the personal data submitted by me will be processed in accordance with the ICANN Privacy Policy, and agree to abide by the website Terms of Service and the Domain Name Registration Data Lookup Terms of Use.

No registry RDAP server was identified for this domain. Attempting lookup using WHOIS service.

Failed to perform lookup using WHOIS service: TLD_NOT_SUPPORTED.

Can anyone help?